# "The task 'generate-sql' has not been registered", when executing php symfony doctrine:build --sql

Tags: symfony-1.4

I tried adding new entities to my project (Symfony 1.4) and I got the `The task 'generate-sql' has not been registered` error when executing `php symfony doctrine:build --sql`.
The command `php symfony doctrine:build --model` executed without errors and the classes were built.
Previously the `build-sql` command was working, I suspect that may be some file is corrupt or missing, there was some file movement between computers involved...

I guess my question is - how to ensure that the task is properly registered?
I have looked in the project files but I cannot yet understand where the connection between `'generate-sql'` in `sfDoctrineBuildSqlTask::execute` and `Doctrine_Task_GenerateSql::execute` is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to figure out which file is missing/corrupted, but that would require significant effort & you may still be missing other vital files. I would just replace the entire contents of the symfony folder in vendors.

Download symfony from the website, delete the old folder, and unpack the framework files. That should cover any library files you would need.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late response. I downloaded the framework again and when it was working, took my existing sources into the new folder structure and built again what's needed.